# Como puedo posicionar elementos dentro de Mapa de Google usando longitut y latitud

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, aplicación-web

En mi pagina Asp.Net C# muestro un mapa de google y en una lista tengo varias direcciones(longitud,latitud) y quiero que en mi mapa Aparezca una referencia a cada una  de ellas ...Como puedo hacerlo??

```
 foreach (var item in lista)
   {
     double? latitud =  item.config.Position.Latitude;
     double? longitud = item.config.Position.Longitude;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No vas a poder realizar esto desde codigo .net

Vas a tener que exponer un `webmethod` en la pagina y enviar estas posiciones como json al cliente, entonces cuando se renderiza la pagina invocas usando `$.ajax` de jquery al webmethod, obtienes el json con las posiciones y las asignas creando los Marker.

[Google Map with JSON](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/885448/Google-Map-with-JSON)

en el articulo se explica esto que menciono.

Desde la funcion javascript `CreateMarker()` se usa el $.ajax para invocar al webmethod quien devuelves el json los las geolocation que debe mostrar en el mapa

Comment: ok..Gracias voy a revisar para hacerlo....

Comment: una vez que lo consigas, agrega la respuesta @EfrainMejiasC así la comunidad crece! y todos aprendemos :D

Comment: @fredyfx es que la respuesta va a ser lo mismo que se plantea en el articulo del link, no puse el codigo porque es algo largo, solo remarque donde debe puntualizar. Basicamente seria definir un webmethod en el aspx que devuelva el json con las posiciones y luego desde codigo cliente usando jquery $.ajax invocarlo para tener los datos y armar los Marker del mapa

Comment: entendido mi estimado :D gracias por colaborar con la comunidad!

Comment: aqui sale bien explicado ...  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/885448/Google-Map-with-JSON

Comment: @EfrainMejiasC pero es el mismo articulo que sugiero en la respuesta

Comment: Si Leandro es el mismoo...solo le respondia A fredyfx...

Comment: gracias :D a darle con todo el power 2.0!